Wait For Element To Be find next xpath In Selenium WebDriver vb.net
Wait For Element To Be find next xpath In Selenium WebDriver vb.net
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim driver As IWebDriver
    driver = New ChromeDriver
    driver.Manage().Window().Maximize()
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://google.com")
    driver.Manage().Window().Maximize()

    Dim wait As New WebDriverWait(WebDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds))
    wait.Until(Function(webDriver)
                   Return webDriver.FindElement(By.Id("someDynamicElement")).Enabled And webDriver.FindElement(By.Id("someDynamicElement")).Displayed
               End Function)

End Sub


Hi, welcome to SO. Could you elaborate on what exactly your problem is, what you've tried to solve it, and an example of what you'd expect to happen?
